# Rencii SSH.NET Shell

Tags: c#, shell, ssh

I am trying to write a terminal app using Shell class from Rencii SSH.NET lib.
Here is my code.

```
var input = Console.OpenStandardInput();
var output = Console.OpenStandardOutput();

var shell = sshClient.CreateShell(input, output, output);
shell.Start();
```

All goes well, except one thing. When I enter command, it sends an extra newline. How can I dispose of that?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried really hard to creating ssh shell from this and tried to find shell controls for wpf but I wasnt successful untill I used this library

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13422/Terminal-Control-Project-C-VT-SSH-Telnet

and it works well with wpf and as it is developed in windows form so would be really easy to implement.
you need to import namespace and import the custom control from dll file and for wpf import namespace

```
xmlns:terminalControl="clr-namespace:WalburySoftware;assembly=TerminalControl"

xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"   
and the control

<WindowsFormsHost Panel.ZIndex="6">

<terminalControl:TerminalEmulator   x:Name="TerminalEmulator" Hostname="192.168.x.x" Password="root" Username="root" ConnectionType="SSH2"></terminalControl:TerminalEmulator>  

</WindowsFormsHost>
```

and from code behind call the TerminalEmulator.Connect()
and you have the terminal control in windows form or wpf